# I need to execute javascript statements, incrementing a variable each time (90 times)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I tried something like this in my JS file, but couldn't get it to work. What I need is to build this code with each "i" incrementing by 1:

```
if (document.form.listname1.checked==true){
var i = 2;
while (i < 90) {
    document.form.listname[i].disabled=true;
    document.form.listname[i].style.borderColor='#999';
    document.form.listname[i].style.background='#999';
    document.form.listname[i].style.borderStyle='solid';
 i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with your code except that you need to close your if statement (so it may be that the real issue is how you are handling the html (can't tell for sure from what you have posted). That said, just a vanilla for loop should work a little better to avoid scoping your `var i` outside the loop (unless you really need `i` for some other subsequent operation).

```
for (let i = 2; i < 90; i++) {
  document.form.listname[i].disabled = true;
  document.form.listname[i].style.borderColor = '#999';
  document.form.listname[i].style.background = '#999';
  document.form.listname[i].style.borderStyle = 'solid';
}
```